# Select count(column) from table of mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database and I am trying to make a website and connect it to my database.
I am trying to count the number of instances in a column but I am having trouble.
I have this so far:

```
$result =("SELECT COUNT(mediaID) FROM media WHERE 1;");

echo "The number of media posted on the system is ".$result."<br>";
```

Comment: That is not how you perform a SQL query from PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have the connection done. Here something is column which you are using to filter the output as desired.

```
$result="select count(mediaID) from media where something="1"";
echo" the sentence".$result"."
```

Comment: And I think you know the variable you have used